# What happens to my caster roll when maintaining a power that targets 5?

Tags: savage-worlds

In Savage World, every 1 Power you maintain is a -1 to your casting roll. If I have a power that targets 5 (and which requires maintaining), is it considered as maintaining 1 power or 5 powers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One power. Basically you can count your castings. So if you've got a multi-target spell like Burrow, you can maintain it on everybody as one spell (you're only casting the spell once, you're just hitting extra people thanks to the Additional targets clause). But if you cast Deflection on 3 people, that would be 3 spells being maintained (since you had to spend 3 actions to do so, rolled to cast three times, etc).

Comment: Essentially, if a Power has the "Additional Targets" option, it counts as 1 maintained Power regardless of how many targets it affects?

Comment: Count the powers that you cast. If you cast Burrow on 5 targets, then Burrow another 5 targets, that's 2 powers to maintain over 10 targets.

Comment: @extrakun, that is correct.  One casting is one power, even if the spell / power has the additional targets ability.